# "*** stack smashing detected ***" with file read and writes

Tags: c, file, pointers, cs50

I'm working with a C program that reads from a single file and uses `sprintf` to write that data into multiple files, I'm going wrong somewhere, but I don't really know where and that results in this error:

> `*** stack smashing detected ***`

The code usable for reproduction is given here:

```
FILE * source=fopen("card.raw","r");// defines source I will read from

char array[512];
int active_read=0;
char * filename;
sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg",i);
FILE *image=fopen(filename, "a"); //my understanding of sprintf to create a file

while(fread(array,sizeof(char *),512,source)==512) // if 512 characters can be detected
{
    if(array[0]==0xff && array[1]==0xd8 && array[2]==0xff && (array[3] & 0xf0==0))
    {
        if(active_read==1)
            fclose(image);
        active_read=1;
        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg",i);
        image=fopen(filename, "a");
        fwrite(array, sizeof(char *),512, image);
        i++;
    }
    else if(active_read==1)
        fwrite(array, sizeof(char *), 512, image);
}
```

I rand the code with my debugger(CS50 Debugger). And I found that the `if` condition is never even checked. It jumps from the `while` loop to the `else if` condition, never does anything and then leaves with the error.

Comment: 1) `filename` is not initialized so the first `sprintf` gives [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) already. 2) `fread(array,sizeof(char *),512,source)` Why `sizeof(char *)`? The `array` is `char[]` so that should be `sizeof(char)` or simply `1`.

Comment: `filename` should be an array, not a pointer.

Comment: `char * filename;` -> `char filename[64];`

Comment: @4386427 Why 64?

Comment: @Mr.JohnnyDoe It was just to show the principle, i.e. select a number sufficiently high so that you never overflow the buffer. In "real" code, you should use `snprintf`

Comment: Also, even with all these changes, I still have a situation where the if condition is not entered

Comment: `active_read` is kind of strange. We can't see how it is initialized and it's only assigned the value 1. You need to posted the code where it is defined and initialized

Comment: it is set to 0 outside the loop. When I look at it with my debugger, the control checks while loop condition. Checks else if, doesn't enter the condition though. And keeps going on. But it never even checks to see if my if statement is correct or not

Comment: @Barmar, It doesn't *have* to be an array, but it should point to a large enough buffer.

Comment: @HAL9000 It doesn't have to be, but there's no particular reason why it needs to be allocated dynamically, so it might as well be.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree that having `filename` be an array would be a good idea in this case, but "should be" are strong words.

Comment: @HAL9000 I didn't mean "must be" in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the problem with `char * filename;` that should be an array, e.g. `char filename[64];`, there is a problem here:

```
(array[3] & 0xf0==0)
```

How is that evaluated?

Is it `((array[3] & 0xf0)==0)` or `(array[3] & (0xf0==0))` ?

Checkout https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence and you see that `==` has higher precedence than `&`. Consequently, you do `0xf0 == 0` first. That's always false (aka zero) so your expression is always false. So the compiler is allowed to (and probably will) optimize the generated code so that the expression isn't evaluated at run time. Instead it always go directly to the `else if` part.

In other words - the compiler is allowed to treat your code as-if it was:

```
while(fread(array,sizeof(char *),512,source)==512) 
{
    if(active_read==1)
        fwrite(array, sizeof(char *), 512, image);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Edit:                           Also notice that this should
be `sizeof(char)` or just 1 (as sizeof(char) is always 1)
as noticed by @Jabberwocky in a comment.

BTW: Be careful with `sprintf` as it may overflow the destination buffer. Consider using `snprintf`instead.

Comment: ```(array[3] & 0xf0)==0xe0``` I made this change and then worked it. The issue isn't whether the if returns true or false. The issue is that the compiler never actually checks if value is true or false

Comment: @Mr.JohnnyDoe The compiler could see that your expression would always be false so it just optimized the code... no reason to check the condition when the result is already known

Comment: @4386427 shouldn't it also be `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char *)`?

Comment: So I will have to look at the if statement again

Comment: @Jabberwocky Good point... I'll update the answer..

Comment: @Mr.JohnnyDoe Quote: "So I will have to look at the if statement again". Just use `((array[3] & 0xf0)==0)`. Then th `if` statement should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @4386427's answer, if your `char` type is signed, the comparison `array[0]==0xff` will always be false, as [seen here](https://godbolt.org/z/vhnf4v) (also a pro tip: try to enable every single warning that your compiler offers).

The reason is that `0xFF` is `255`, which is promoted to an `int`, and then compared to a `signed char` which is also promoted to int, but has a possible range of values from -128 to 127.

To make sure that your code works properly if `char` is `signed`, either change the `array` declaration to use `unsigned char`, or cast to unsigned before comparison:

```
 if ( (unsigned char)array[0] == 0xff && 
      (unsigned char)array[1] == 0xd8 &&
      (unsigned char)array[2] == 0xff &&
      ((unsigned char)array[3] & 0xf0) == 0 )
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looked like the general notion of my if condition was causing problems:

`if(array[0]==0xff && array[1]==0xd8 && array[2]==0xff)`

Since I had been comparing a single character from a character array with a byte. I had changed the type of `array` to `BYTE *` and the problem was solved